# AS3 exporting html5 with CreateJS using Flash Professional CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, html

I am using CS6 and exporting to html5 using the CreateJS extension. It seems the action-script will not work unless you go into the Java file and tweak it.

How can I tweak the ActionScript to work in the HTML5 export file using CreateJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript is ignored by the Toolkit for CreateJS. You can use some JavaScript using this syntax:

```
/* JS
this.gotoAndPlay("label");
*/
```

For future questions, I recommend http://community.createjs.com, which is actively monitored.
Cheers,